# should I set the content view on activityResult when working with in-app-billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a question about handling a purchase that the user makes. In my case, I want to remove the adds when user makes a purchase. I have two versions of my activity_main layout - one with adds and one without. I am wondering where and how to set the layout when the user makes a purchase.
I am thinking something like this:

```
if (adsDisabled == true){
setContentView(R.layout.mainNoAds)
} else{
setContentView(R.layout.main
}
```

the code I private variable listener:

```
 private IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchasedFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
            return;
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_REMOVE_ADDS)) {
            // consume the purchase and update the UI
        }
    }
};
```

and I am calling it when my menu item is tapped:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if(id == R.id.action_remove_adds){
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this,SKU_REMOVE_ADDS,1,mPurchasedFinishedListener,"");
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and this is my onActicityResult code:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a rather heavy-handed approach, as you're either duplicating quite a lot of your layout content between the two (ad/non-ad) definitions or include one layout in the other. If you're interested in just the `AdView` going away, why not simply set its visibility to `View.GONE`?

One thing worth nothing is that I'm not sure if hiding it away makes the ad requests stop and the `AdView` pause implicitly, so that might be worth taking a look at.